# Need help understanding onto function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let function $g$ from $V = \{1,2,3,4\}$ into V be defined by: $g(n)=3$.

I'm having trouble understanding why $g$ is not onto. I understand why it is not one-to-one but, since all the $y$ in $Y$, are mapped at least one $x$ in $X$ such that f(x) = y, wouldn't the function be onto?

Comment: What is the mysterious $X$?

Comment: For surjective functions, all the $x \in X$ need not be mapped from..

Comment: It is impossible to say whether or not $g$ is onto unless you clearly state the domain and codomain of $g$.

Comment: @David Wouldn't the domain be 1,2,3,4 and the codomain be 3 for this case?

Comment: @Mattos Fixed my post.

Comment: Yes we cant say anything about the ontoness of the function unless the Domain and Codomain are known. If $g:V\rightarrow V$ then $g$ is not onto. Since onto functions satisfies $Range=Codomain$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $g$ is a function from $V$ to $V$.  To say that $g$ is onto means:

> for every $y$ in the codomain, there exists $x$ in the domain such that $y=f(x)$.

In this case, the domain and codomain are both the same, so:

> for every $y$ in $V$, there exists $x$ in $V$ such that $y=f(x)$.

This is not true because $f(x)$ is always $3$; so, if we take for example $y=1$, we find that there is no $x\in V$ such that $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Thank's @David, that gave me some insight. For completeness, the domain and codomain are 1,2,3,4 right?

Comment: @brto In your latest edit of the question, that's right.